# Javascript 3d card (cube) interactive rotation

Tags: javascript, 3d, mouseevent, interactive, card

I am looking for a (easy) solution to have a id-card rotating in 3-D with mouse event.
(like a cube but flat with thickness) using
Javascript (engine) , HTML5.
With a maped foreground and background - image.
Movement should be slow rotating automatically but also on mouse - events.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Image:

[image: rotating card]

Thanks sepp.

Comment: Can you add an example?

Comment: like: https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/id-card-75ce40e32e7e47dab6087e3a1a6133d4  with mouse events and should rotate slowly automatically